# Get common values out of a list in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, set

### I have below list:

```
a=[{'list1': ['35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50,51,52']},
   {'list2': ['1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50,51,52']}]
```

I want to get out the common values from both list1 and list2. I have written

```
x = set(a[list_2015]).intersection(a[list_2016])
```

But it throws as error:

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple
```

### I want the output to be:

```
{35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52}
```

Comment: Your problem is that your lists consist of one large string element, instead of a numerous integers (as you might have thought). So basically you first need to convert that string to a sequence of integers and then your code using `intersection` will work just fine!

Answer (score 3):

This is one way:

```
res = set(map(int, a[0]['list1'][0].split(','))) & \
      set(map(int, a[1]['list2'][0].split(',')))

{35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52}
```

Note `&` operator is syntactic sugar for `set.intersection`.